# Android fresco lib , apply custom filter

Tags: android, image, filter, fresco

i'm using fresco to display images to my app. Right now i'm trying to apply some filters to my images but the problem is that the filter library only results Bitmap. But the draweeView.setImageBitmap is deprecated.

I also tried with a post processor like this

```
    MeshPostprocessor meshPostprocessor = new MeshPostprocessor();
    meshPostprocessor.setFilter(filters.get(0));

    draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_image);

    ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(image)
            .setPostprocessor(meshPostprocessor)
            .setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(100, 100))
            .build();

    PipelineDraweeController controller = (PipelineDraweeController)
            Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setImageRequest(request)
                    .setOldController(draweeView.getController())
                    .build();
    draweeView.setController(controller);
```

and here is the PostProcessor

```
public static class MeshPostprocessor extends BaseRepeatedPostProcessor {
    private AbstractConfig.ImageFilterInterface filter;

    public void setFilter(AbstractConfig.ImageFilterInterface filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
        update();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "meshPostprocessor";
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Bitmap bitmap) {
        bitmap = filter.renderImage(bitmap);
    }
}
```

so when I click on a filter i just run this

```
meshPostprocessor.setFilter(colorFilterConfig.get(position));
```

I tried with the debugger, the code goes through all the methods (setFilter , process etc..) but the image is not changing at all...

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need a `BaseRepeatedPostProcessor` in your case. 
A normal `BasePostProcessor` should be sufficient here.

However, the issue seems to be your custom filter:

```
@Override
public void process(Bitmap bitmap) {
    bitmap = filter.renderImage(bitmap);
}
```

I suppose it returns a different Bitmap? This does not work in Java / for Fresco.

If your filter can do the processing in place, you can use `process(Bitmap bitmap)` and directly modify the given bitmap (e.g. `bitmap.setPixel(...)`).

If you cannot do it in place, you can override `process(Bitmap destBitmap, Bitmap sourceBitmap)` instead and modify `destBitmap`.

If your bitmap changes it's size, you can override `CloseableReference<Bitmap> process(Bitmap sourceBitmap, PlatformBitmapFactory bitmapFactory)`. However, in this case make sure to actually use the provided `bitmapFactory` to create the new bitmap to be efficient.

For more information, take a look at http://frescolib.org/docs/modifying-image.html for more information or check out the [JavaDoc for `BasePostprocessor`](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/b3a41a9838a1fd886db35d7f9984ac52a813f692/imagepipeline/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/request/BasePostprocessor.java).

Comment: I needed the repeatedProcessor because i should be able to change the filters many times. Your post was actually helpfull. All i needed to do is just add the super in the end

Answer (score 0):

ok so the way I solved this is by adding a super call on the process like this

```
@Override
public void process(Bitmap dest, Bitmap source) {
        Bitmap filtered = filter.renderImage(source, intensity);
        super.process(dest, filtered);   
}
```

i didn't noticed that you have to call super in order for the changes to have effect.

Comment: Well, this works because if you take a look at the source code, super does `Bitmaps.copyBitmap(destBitmap, sourceBitmap);`. Normally, you should not call super when you override. You can call `Bitmaps.copyBitmap(destBitmap, sourceBitmap);` instead. However, not having the temporary Bitmap filtered would be ideal since you now have 3 instead of 2 bitmaps in memory, and your filtered one will likely live on the Java heap as well and needs a GC to be cleaned up, which is not ideal.